# "UnboundLocalError" reported on wrong line number

Tags: python

For example:

```
$ cat -n foo.py
     1  def f():
     2      str = len
     3      str = str('abc')
     4  #   len = len('abc')
     5  f()
$ python2.7 foo.py
$
```

It runs successfully so there are no problems with line #2 and line #3. But after I uncomment line #4:

```
$ cat -n bar.py
     1  def f():
     2      str = len
     3      str = str('abc')
     4      len = len('abc')
     5  f()
$ python2.7 bar.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bar.py", line 5, in <module>
    f()
  File "bar.py", line 2, in f
    str = len
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'len' referenced before assignment
$
```

Now it reports error so there must be something wrong with the uncommented line #4 but why the Traceback error is reported on line #2?

Comment: Just a heads-up: the author of a question you recently answered [has asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355936/an-answer-and-comments-just-disappear) why you deleted your answer, in case you want to weigh in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a answer in Programming FAQ

> This is because when you make an assignment to a variable in a scope,
>   that variable becomes local to that scope and shadows any similarly
>   named variable in the outer scope.

Read complete here : [Why am I getting an UnboundLocalError when the variable has a value?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

When len is commented it is consider as a build in function [len()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len)

```
def f():
    str = len
    print type(str)
    str = str('abc')
    # len = len('abc')
    print type(len)

f()

<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

Answer (score 0):

with L4 commented, `len` is parsed as function `len()`.

after uncomment L4, `len` is parsed as a local variable.